# Android : Go to the next layout when spesifique html page or url is loading in webview

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a content locker from a cpi network and I want to include it in my android application.

the concept of the content locker is when the user complete the offers , go  automatically to a specific URL .

what I want to do is, if a specific URL is loading, to go to the next layout